# VS2015 freezes when opening solution from workspace

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, source-control-explorer

I have a repo that is stored on a TFS server. I used Source Control Explorer in VS2015 to bring down the files to my development machine. I mapped the workspace to the files and I have some solutions within my workspace. When I try and open the solution VS2015 churns away until the following dialog pops up and VS2015 freezes up and the UI become unresponsive.

[image]

I end up having to terminate the process and restart Visual Studio. I have tried removing all files and deleting the workspace. Then trying to pull down the files again. It is only when I try to open the solution that this error occurs.

Comment: Can you share the detailed steps to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There maybe something wrong with you source control bindings. You need to make sure  you have added the **entire solution to source control**.

If the solution and projects are already added you can inspect your binding to see if anything is missing. Some files in the solution may not have corresponding source control bindings.

To inspect your solution bindings select the solution in solution explorer and then *choose File->Source Control->Advanced->Change Source Control*... in the Visual Studio menu.

Go through for any projects where Connected is not selected or status is not Valid. To connect a project simply click the Connect button and the project is added to source control. You could also try to unbind the project and then rebind it again which may do the trick. Then remove all files, remap and  pull down the files again.